# Массовое добавление маркеров на карту на один слой(более 4000)

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый день!

Есть ли возможность добавления большого количества маркеров на одном слое? Может быть существуют какие-либо специальные программы для этого или платные версии карт.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать группировать маркеры в kml слои заранее и сжимать в kmz. Так на одном слое можно отображать до 10000 объектов. Если же маркеры задаются динамически, то задача очень трудоемка: по оптимизации и по ресурсам железа.
http://vremenno.net/js/kml-in-google-maps-api-v3/